# Unable to install python3-tk in my ubuntu machine 16.04

Tags: package-management, python3, pycharm, tkinter

I am trying to make a very first desktop application using tkinter in pycharm like this.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
mLabel = Label(root, text="This is Header")
mLabel.pack
mLabel.mainloop()
```

But I got an exception saying

```
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter', please install the python3-tk package
```

And I tried to install the python3-tk like this

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

But I then got an error about `install-info`

```
ronem:::ronem:~$ sudo apt-get install python3-tk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libfftw3-single3:i386 libgomp1:i386 libpam-systemd:i386 
libpulsedsp:i386 libtdb1:i386
libwebrtc-audio-processing-0:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
blt tk8.6-blt2.5
Suggested packages:
blt-demo tix python3-tk-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
blt python3-tk tk8.6-blt2.5
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 437 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/604 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,117 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up install-info (6.1.0.dfsg.1-5) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 3: /etc/environment: CLASSPATH: not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit 
status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
ronem:::ronem:~$
```

Please guide me through What I am missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
cat /etc/environment
```

Check if there is a line in `/etc/environment` that contains the string `CLASSPATH` which doesn't belong in `/etc/environment`. You should comment out everything from `/etc/environment` except for the first line (the setting of `PATH` which starts with `PATH=`) by preceding each line to be commented out by a `#` character. Open the `/etc/environment` file for editing in nano text editor with the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

<sub>**Nano editor keyboard shortcuts**</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file to its current location.</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.</sub>

Comment: I get this while using cat etc/environment

ronem:::ronem:~$ cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/tomcat/bin"
CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
CLASSPATH = /opt/tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar:/opt/tomcat/lib/jsp-api.jar
ronem:::ronem:~$

Comment: Holly molly . You rocks Friend . commenting the CLASSATH line solved this issue. Thanks a ton